# Cómo fijar correctamente un InitialValue en un TextFormField?

Tags: firebase, formularios, flutter

Quiero definir un valor inicial desde una Base de Datos dentro de un TexxtFormField y no logro hacerlo, la caja de texto permanece vacía. El código para definir el valor inicial (_stringAnimalesOrigen) es el siguiente:

```
class TrasadoPage extends StatefulWidget {


  @override
  _TrasadoPageState createState() => _TrasadoPageState();
}

class _TrasadoPageState extends State<TrasadoPage> {
  final formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();

  TrasladoModel traslado          = new TrasladoModel();
  LoteActualBloc loteActualBloc   = new LoteActualBloc();
  LoteModel loteOrigen            = LoteModel();
  final _prefs                    = new PreferenciasUsuario();

String _stringAnimalesOrigen;
    
@override
void initState() { 
  loteActualBloc.cargarLoteActual(_prefs.idEmpresa, _prefs.idEstanque).then((value){
  setState(() {
    loteOrigen = value;
    _stringAnimalesOrigen   = loteOrigen.numAnimales.toString();
  });
  });
  super.initState();
}
```

La construcción del Build y el TextFormField es como sigue:

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {


    print(_stringAnimalesOrigen); //Imprime el número 85000
    

    return SafeArea(
      child: Scaffold(
        body: _cajaNumeroDoble('Animales\nhacia ${estanqueDestino.nombreRef}', FontAwesomeIcons.fish, 'uns   ',
                                      _validarNumero, _stringAnimalesOrigen, (value) => traslado.numAnimales = int.parse(value), context)),

      ),
    );
  }

Widget _cajaNumeroDoble(String etiqueta, IconData icono, String etiquetaFin, Function validator, 
              String valorInicial, Function onSaved, BuildContext context){

    return TextFormField(
            textAlign: TextAlign.center,
            style: TextStyle(fontSize: 25.0),
            keyboardType: TextInputType.numberWithOptions(),
            decoration: InputDecoration(
              border: InputBorder.none,
              suffixText: etiquetaFin,
              suffixStyle: TextStyle(fontSize: 10.0, color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor),
            ),
            initialValue: valorInicial, //Si este campo lo cambio por cualquier otro String, se despliega correctamente como valor inicial
            onSaved: onSaved,
            validator: validator,
            inputFormatters: <TextInputFormatter>[
              WhitelistingTextInputFormatter.digitsOnly,
              BlacklistingTextInputFormatter.singleLineFormatter,
          ),
  }
```

El valor Inicial Definido como _stringAnimalesOrigen está pasando correctamente al build (el número 85000 se imprime en consola), sin embargo **la caja de texto permanece vacía**.

Si pongo un texto diferente como parámetro dentro de InitialValue, el texto se despliega correctamente en el campo.Igualmente si dentro de la función _cajaNumeroDoble cambio lavariable _stringAnimalesOrigen por cualquier otro 'texto', el campo funciona correctamente y despliega el valor inicial. Sin embargo, con la variable _stringAnimalesOrigen no despliega nada.

Comment: Al inicio _stringAnimalesOrigen es nulo o vacío, por lo que el textfield toma ese valor, y ya no puedes modificarlo ni haciendo setState.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Al inicio `_stringAnimalesOrigen` es nulo o vacío, por lo que el `TextField` toma ese valor y ya no puedes modificarlo ni haciendo `setState`.

Lo que debes hacer es usar un `TextEditingController`, asignarlo al `TextField` y luego modificar el valor de ese controller.

```dart
class _TrasadoPageState extends State<TrasadoPage> {

final textController = TextEditingController();


.... 

@override
void initState() { 
  loteActualBloc.cargarLoteActual(_prefs.idEmpresa, _prefs.idEstanque).then((value){
  setState(() {
    loteOrigen = value;
    textController.text = loteOrigen.numAnimales.toString();
  });
  });
  super.initState();
}

...


    return TextFormField(
            controller: textController,
            textAlign: TextAlign.center,
            style: TextStyle(fontSize: 25.0),
            keyboardType: TextInputType.numberWithOptions(),
            decoration: InputDecoration(
              border: InputBorder.none,
              suffixText: etiquetaFin,
              suffixStyle: TextStyle(fontSize: 10.0, color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor),
            ),
            onSaved: onSaved,
            validator: validator,
            inputFormatters: <TextInputFormatter>[
              WhitelistingTextInputFormatter.digitsOnly,
              BlacklistingTextInputFormatter.singleLineFormatter,
          ),
```

Recuerda quitar el initialValue, dado que no puede esta un textController y un initialValue al mismo tiempo.

Comment: Bien. Me queda algo por resolver... dado que la función cajaNumeroDoble es para reusarla en la misma página, cómo le asigno diferentes textEditingController a cada campo?

Comment: A tu funcion pasale ese nuevo parametro TextEditingControllee y listo.

Comment: Perfect. Te hice una pequeña edición

Answer (score -1):

Yo utilizaría async_redux de Marc Galsberg en https://pub.dev/packages/async_redux , que es un almacén de valores inmutables modificables basado en Redux. También se puede hacer usando InheritedWidget.